# Issue Updating Asset Index:S3 Product Downloads

Tags: assets, s3

We recently added a large file (3gb) to our S3 location, and upon updating the assets index, the file is not being recognized.

The file is accessible and we have tested download directly.

Additionally, when we attempt to update the asset index, files that were previously indexed are now showing an error intermittently (Missing files: The following files could not be found. Should they be deleted from the index?)

Any ideas?

Comment: Any errors getting logged in `craft/storage/runtime/logs` when you update Asset indexes?

Comment: @BradBell I ran through multiple log files and it appears there are no related errors in the logs.

Comment: When you run the update asset indexes tool, do it with your browser's console open and see if 1) there are any JS errors and 2) any of the requests come back as something other than 200 O.K.

Comment: @BradBell I had checked that earlier and all 200 OK

Comment: If you think it's a bug, shoot an email to support@craftcms.com along with relevant details (CP/FTP access, etc.) and we'll investigate.